# Geting a data plan in Japan as a tourist

Tags: japan, cellphones, data-plans

I will be visiting Japan for two weeks as a tourist. I would like to have Internet access on my phone at all times, and found that there are some mobile data options for tourists. How do they actually work? Especifically:

Can I bring my european phone, put the sim card in and it works or will I need to rent/buy a japanese terminal?
How is the signal through Japan? Will it work only in big cities, on most populated areas or all through Japan?
Where can I buy them? 
What is the cost and the data cap like?
What is the process of geting one? Will I need to sign a contract, show them my ID and all that or can i just pay and get the card inmediatly?

This is all both to be able to make a decision beforehand if it is indeed worthwile and to make sure I dont get scammed once I get there.

Comment: Please note that English is not my first language AND that I'm writing this on mobile, so I'm sorry for any mistakes on the grammar.

Comment: That question is related, but doesent answer most of thee things i'm concerned with (whether my phone will accept it, price...). Plus the info that i've managed to find through internet suggest that having them mailed to you at the airport or hotel is no longer an option and that they sell them directly at the airport, so not even that part is updated.

Comment: The answer includes llinks to providers' websites, where your questions are answered.

Comment: @Daniferrito 1. If it is Sim-Free yes, otherwise you will need to rent one.
2. Japan has almost the whole country covered by most providers (especially Docomo whose parent company NTT owns the lines) unless you are in a valley, underground, the alps or some other remote area (ie. the Hokkaido countryside) and even then you are likely to get signal.
3. As previous.
4. Refer to the linked question's answer.
5. See the link.
6. See the link.
7. You will need to show ID (your passport usually) even when buying from the vending machines in both Narita and Haneda.

Answer (score 0):

I have also traveled two weeks in Japan and I was in need of a data plan. What I ended up with was I rented a pocket wifi for two weeks. I didnt really have a phone call to make and plus, most SIMs have limited data unless you purchase a really expensive one. Make sure to order online your pocket wifi in advance in order to to pick it up on the airport post office.